# Unable to activate the SSE instruction set by "-march=native" in gcc or any other flags in Core2 chip

Tags: gcc, sse, simd, mmx

My machine is Core2 microarchitecture and I tried to compile some arithmetic code targeting the SSE instruction set. I searched on the web and official manual, and I believe that all I need to do is to add the flag `-march=native`, because my chip supports SSE.

But when I use  `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target -v` to check if the flag really works, the result displayed on-screen is not what I expected.  For example：

```
-msse                               [disabled]
-msse2                              [disabled]
-msse2avx                           [disabled]
-msse3                              [disabled]
-msse4                              [disabled]
-msse4.1                            [disabled]
-msse4.2                            [disabled]
-msse4a                             [disabled]
-msse5                              
-msseregparm                        [disabled]
-mssse3                             [disabled]
```

I find all the SSE (and even MMX) instructions are disabled.
Can anybody tell me why and how to solve it?
Many thanks！

Comment: And I know another way to active the option is to add the flags like -mmsse ...manually. But, I am curiosity, why march=native doesn't works in my system:core2,Ubuntu 12.04(64bit system), gcc 4.6.3

Comment: I wouldn't rely on: `native` - try: `-march=core2`.

Comment: I get the same result when I try -march=core2

Answer (score 5):

The output of `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target -v` does not include the overrides defined by `-march`, as gcc returns the output prior to running the code which handles the architecture specific overrides.

See the [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39851) on this matter, and specifically that it keeps confusing users, such as myself.